# Merge two data.tables / data.frames with x having multiple instances of i and y having a single instance of i, without joining to entire table

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table

Data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1337)
dat <- data.table(source = rep(c('A','B','C'), 100),
              indicator = rep(c('do','this','to','my','favorite','thing'), 50),
              value = sample(1:1000, 300))
src <- data.table(source = c('A','B','C'),
              dataset = c('Business','Sales','Profits'),
              metadata = c('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                           'consectetur adipiscing elit',
                           'Sed dictum leo ac hendrerit sagittis'))
dat[order(source, indicator),]
```

Now I know I can merge them via `dat[src, on = 'source']`, however this applies the data in `src` to all rows of `dat`. My dataset has millions of rows and R cannot allocate enough memory to perform this merge. I would like to perform the merge, but only include the data from `src` on the first occurrence of the `src` in the table. The data that would have been duplicated by the merge could be replaced with either `""` or `NA`.

Essentially I want something that looks like this after merging (sample of desired output):

```
source  indicator  value dataset   metadata
A             do     18  Business  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
A           this     22  NA        NA
A             to      5  NA        NA
...
B             do     42  Sales     consectetur adipiscing elit
B           this    432  NA        NA
B             to    888  NA        NA
...
C             do    118  Profits   Sed dictum leo ac hendrerit sagittis
C           this      7  NA        NA
C             to     15  NA        NA
```

The following code gets close to what I want, but does not apply to the first occurrence of a new source:

```
u <- unique(dat, by = 'source')
d <- dat[duplicated(dat, by = 'source')
u <- u[src, on = 'source']
total <- rbindlist(list(u, d), fill = TRUE)
```

However the second occurrence of the unique `source` does not have the necessary information:

```
> total[98:102]
   source indicator value dataset metadata
1:      A        my   498    <NA>     <NA>
2:      A        my   275    <NA>     <NA>
3:      A        my   733    <NA>     <NA>
4:      B  favorite   912    <NA>     <NA>
5:      B  favorite   613    <NA>     <NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use an update join:

```
cols <- setdiff(names(src), "source")

dat[src, on = .(source), mult = "first", (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols))]
```

which gives (same rows as used in the question):

> ```
> > dat[98:102]
>    source indicator value dataset                    metadata
> 1:      A        my   870    <NA>                        <NA>
> 2:      A        my    47    <NA>                        <NA>
> 3:      A        my   546    <NA>                        <NA>
> 4:      B  favorite   372   Sales consectetur adipiscing elit
> 5:      B  favorite   970    <NA>                        <NA>
> ```

Comment: For my use case, I had to add an extra step that solved the problem: `setorderv(dat, cols = c('source', 'dataset', 'indicator'), na.last = TRUE)` to get the rows in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

We can specify  the `mult`

```
dat1[src, on = .(source), mult = 'first']
```

Comment: Unfortunately that only produces a three row `data.table`, and I want all the rows in `dat`

Comment: @JoshuaGrant  IN that case, try the reverse `src[dat1, on = .(source), mult = 'first']`

Comment: That still populates all data, output is the same as `dat[src, on = .(source)]`, with the only difference being a rearrangement of the columns.

Comment: @JoshuaGrant  Please show expected output on a smaller data, that would make it easier to understand